# Express node.js - Does the render function has a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

After rendering my index.html (which works fine), I would like to send some additional data via sockets. For that, I would need a promise for the rendering process. At the moment, the code runs synchron. The socket data is sent and moments later the data is overwritten due to the later ending rendering process. Looking for something like:

```
res.render('index', {title: "XYZ"})
.then(function(){

//.. do something

});
```

Is there a different approach? Or is the only solution to ask for the data via the client?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What version of Express are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the render function has a promise?

[The documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) doesn't mention one, so presumably not.

> For that, I would need a promise for the rendering process.

Not necessarily, just some kind of notification that the data had been sent. Promises are one kind of notification, but not the only kind.

The docmentation shows that `render` will call a callback function with the rendered HTML, so you could use that callback to send the HTML along with whatever you want to have follow it:

```
res.render("index", {title: "XYZ"}, function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        // ...send an error response...
        return;
    }
    res.send(html);
    // ...send your other stuff here...
});
```

But if you want a promise, you could use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) on `res.render`. It's a bit of a pain because `promisify` doesn't make handling `this` straightforward, so you have to use `bind`:

```
const resRender = util.promisify(res.render.bind(res));
// ...
resRender("index", {title: "XYZ"})
.then(html => {
    res.send(html);
    // ...send your other stuff here...
})
.catch(err => {
    // ...send an error response...
});
```

---

You've said you're sending further information "via sockets." That makes it sound to me like the further information you're sending **isn't** being sent via the `res` response, but via a separate channel.

If so, and if you want to wait to send that until the response is sent, you can start your socket sending in response to the [`finish` event](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish) on the response:

```
res.on("finish", () => {
    // Send your socket message here
});
res.render("index", {title: "XYZ"});
```

(Remember that an [Express `Response` object](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) is an enhanced version of the Node.js `ServerResponse` object, which is what provides this event.)

But even then, all that means is that the data has been handed over to the OS for transmission to the client. From the documentation:

> ...this event is emitted when the last segment of the response headers and body have been handed off to the operating system for transmission over the network. It does not imply that the client has received anything yet.

I don't think you have anything beyond that to hook into.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the quick reply. If I send the socket message after the `res.send(html)`, the socket message and the client work is still faster and the results are overwritten by the render process. Still have the same problem. It works only, if I do following: `//res.send(html);`. But then, as anticipated, the loading process won´t stop and after a certain time the page disappears.

Comment: @Harald - I've added to the answer. I think you're saying that you're sending a message to the client via a *different channel*, rather than via the response. You're going to struggle to coordinate those well.